# Why doesn't the 2rd function run, in this javascript's async example?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
var async = require('async');

function f1() {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('111');},300);
}

function f2() {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('222');},100);
}

async.series([f1,f2], function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

It prints:

```
111
```

No `222`? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f1()` and `f2()` are expected to complete asynchronously, so they are given a callback to invoke when they are "done".  Try this instead:

```
var async = require('async');

function f1(done) {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('111'); done(); },300);
}

function f2(done) {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log('222'); done(); },100);
}

async.series([f1,f2], function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

---

Edit: regarding the "why", it's because `f1()` gets invoked immediately, and so your initial `setTimeout()` is scheduled as expected.  However, since you are never telling `async` that `f1()` is done, it never invokes `f2()`.